# How to list all collection IDs of a firestore project with the REST API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Searching through the google cloud docs and found ways to list projects such as
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/list
and also this one to list collection ids when you get the document path
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/listCollectionIds#google.firestore.v1.Firestore.ListCollectionIds
but still can't seem to find a REST API method to fetch all of the collection ids in a firestore project without a document path and just the project id.

Answer (score 1):

You may be encountering this (long-standing) issue:
[Parent parameter has incorrect pattern for some of methods in discovery API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170376899).

To be clear, not all Collections are owned by the root. You are unable to enumerate Collections that are children of Documents without navigating through the hierarchy.

Comment: Yea I understand that, I don't want any sub collections of a document, I just want the root collections of a firestore project but according to the link you sent it seems like the engineering team at Firebase has some work to do on it, I might try and contact them and see what's going on with it.

Comment: You should star the issue. There's no need to comment ping. Star'ing the issue is a signal to Google that this issue concerns you too.

Comment: So I found out that something like this https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectID/databases/(default)/documents:listCollectionIds works and you have to pass the access token as a header